# Responding in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, rest

I want to respond in a Net Core rest api post request with a json but I don't want to return anything. So I know that I can return the json it's easy but I need to do some other calls with database after returning, just  to improve the performance because the db call require too much time. So I thought maybe is another way to respond a request and do some other stuff after.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vague question, but it sounds like you need to investigate using a background worker to offload the actual processing from the API.  Typically you would accept their POST request, send that request to your background process (commonly by putting it into some sort of message queue) and then return immediately instead of waiting for the processing to complete.

There are many ways to handle background processing in ASP.Net Core.  You can look at a "Worker Service," or if you want to leverage the Cloud, look at something like Azure Functions or AWS Lambda.  These "Code/Function as a Service" platforms are ideal for async/background processing, depending on your scenarios.

I use Azure Functions a lot for this stuff.  Package the request/task up as a message, place it in a message queue, then have the Function watch the queue and process the messages as needed.